# an adverb describing something you do with total satisfaction

Tags: word-request

> he ___ accepted the fact without any skepticism nor arguing.

I tried searching but it didn't help because I couldn't describe the word correctly.

Comment: Could you give more detail about what, *exactly* his feeling is?  "Without any skepticism or argument" already implies "agreement", so what is the additional, and possibly **subtle**, emotion you want to convey?  The reason I ask is that, if he was really completely **satisfied** with some fact, there would be no reason to suggest he could have argued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first instinct is to use the word [**wholeheartedly**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wholeheartedly).

From Merriam-Webster's definition of its adjectival form:

> **2** : marked by complete earnest commitment : free from all reserve or hesitation
>   // gave the proposal *wholehearted* approval

Although the definition doesn't mention *satisfaction*, I believe that meaning is implicit.

---

Note that with the use of this word (or any similar word), *without any skepticism nor arguing* becomes redundant.

In other words, it's more natural to simply say:

> He **wholeheartedly** accepted the fact.